# Trying to use babel generated code in .Net Core Razor pages

Tags: javascript, razor, .net-core, babeljs

I've installed babel and am able to take a js file and convert it.

But I can't work out how to make that new file work on a page.

I'm using async/await, and with default options it causes:

Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

I've tried playing around with options, but they all end up using things like **require**, causing different errors:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs",
     //   "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "debug": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Any tips on how to get this working in .Net Core using basic html pages?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. Here was the key:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill

I don't need to play with options. I just needed to include the distribution polyfill.min.js